# How to convert all columns value to rows and then check for a particular column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a table like this:

```
student | group
1       | A
2       | B
1       | B
3       | C
```

i want to produce the output like the following:

```
Student | Group_A | Group_B | Group_C
1       | Yes     | Yes     | 
2       |         | Yes     | 
3       |         |         | Yes
```

Do anybody have any idea how can I produce this type of report? I tried several ways using Pivot and Unpivot but it's not working here

Comment: Is there a fixed number of groups, or is that dynamic?

Comment: it's dynamic. but when the query will be executed, it will give output based on the table's that column value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for pivot.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

```
declare @students table(id int, type_ nvarchar)

insert into @students
values(1, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(3, 'C'),
(1, 'B');


select result.id Student,
    iif(result.A = 1, 'Yes', 'No') Group_A,
    iif(result.B = 1, 'Yes', 'No') Group_B,
    iif(result.C = 1, 'Yes', 'No') Group_C
from (
    select *
    from @students a
    pivot(count(type_) for type_ in (
                [A],
                [B],
                [C]
                )) as pivotExample
    ) result;
```

If a dynamic pivot is required, I would refer you to this:

[SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for. Thanks